# Android Studio - Gradle Failure - Intel Atom x86

Tags: gradle, sdk, x86, intel

I need your help please,

I imported an old Project in my Android Studio. I solved actually many problems, but now there is a problem i can´s solve. My Android Studio says:

(Failed to sync Gradle project 'ChatSecureAndroid')
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'Intel Corporation:Intel Atom x86 System Image:10' in: C:\Android\sdk
Open Android SDK Manager

I allready Installed all points in Android SDK Manager (API 10).

My target SDK version is 21 - i also Installed all points in Android SDK Manager (API 21)

Someone know any way i can try? :/

Greetings and Thanks,

felix

Comment: did u solve this problem. I am facing same. Trying to add `chatsecureAndroid` project in android studio

Answer (score 0):

I think you should grep all the build.gradle files under your project tree with string "compileSdkVersion" to see if you have all the SDK platforms installed with the API level they declared.